# Spyder keeps dying

Tags: python, spyder

I am using spyder and it keeps broken down whenever I run. (In detail, the spyder window turned off at all)

When I searched, people say it is the memory problem but the solutions are for jupyter notebook but I do not use it.

Could you please let me know the solution for spyder?

How to fix the problem that the spyder keeps dying?

My python version is 3.8.11 and install spyder in 3.8 python version.

Comment: Have you tried VSCode editor? It's better solution than Spyder

Comment: @kj-crypto No.. I did not try it. Can it be the solution for the spyder broken down?

Comment: @Jin VSCode is a replacement for Spyder.

Comment: @Jin AFAIK VSC is better than Spyder. Try it out

Comment: Umm.. Ok I will try it. Thank you so much!

Comment: I don't think that changing to VSCode answers to this questio though

Comment: Try re-installing Spyder or un-install python and run it to see what happens... we don't have enough details to help you

Comment: This may happen as your Spyder version is incompatible with your Ipython and your Python version. Can you please add more details of the version in your post?

Comment: I see. The python version is 3.8.11 and the Ipython version in spyder is 3.9. I did not know that those are different. I will try to upgrade the python version or reinstall spyder.

Comment: Does the version difference make the spyder slow? If I use two spyder, the speed becomes really slow and then broken down.  It is still shown even though I reinstall the spyder at the same python version.

Comment: I wonder how you can open two spyder? Anyhow, the compatible Ipython is `>=7.31.1,<8.0.0`. What is your spyder version? You can check out the link here and try to do some self troubleshooting https://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/troubleshooting/first-steps.html

Comment: Thank you for helping me. With the helps of you, I could understand spyder and use it better :)